# conditional mean in rolling

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I need to find the avg (p) of rolling 10 days data and above avg (ap)and below avg (bp) of the same data

for example I have data in a column from 1, 2, 3, .... 8, 9, 10.

```
p = 5.5
ap = avg of nos above p; i.e. 6+7+8+9+10/5 = 8
bp = similarly 3
```

here is what I have tried.

```
df["AP"] = df["O"].where(df["O"] >= df["p"]).shift().rolling(min_periods=1, window=10).mean()
df["BP"] = df["O"].where(df["O"] < df["p"]).shift().rolling(min_periods=1, window=10).mean()
```

but I don't get the desired result.
i also tried

```
df["AP"] = df["O"].shift().rolling(min_periods=1, window=10).quantile(0.75)
```

but this is different from what I intend to do on a larger dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to BENY I found the answer.

```
df["AP"] = df["O"].shift().rolling(min_periods=1, window=10).apply(lambda x: x[x>x.mean()].mean())
df["AP"] = df["O"].shift().rolling(min_periods=1, window=10).apply(lambda x: x[x<x.mean()].mean())
```

Thanks.